# Stacking single column in amcharts 4 on hover

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, amcharts, amcharts4

Please check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-daggu3) link

Here on hover you can see a tooltip with different counts, I wanted to show a stacked column on hover, something like this  [image: this] I have tried creating a second series on 'over' event of first series (same can be seen in the code), but it is not working.

Is there a way to achieve this in amcharts?

Comment: share your code

Comment: It is already shared in the stackblitz link of the question

Comment: It would be better if you include the main parts of your stackblitz in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should create a "normal" stacked column chart with multiple series for each data value:

```js
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "error"; // "pass", ...
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.name = "Research";
series.stacked = true;
```

If that works you can set the `fill` and `stroke` color of all series to the same value:

```js
series.fill = am4core.color('#ececec');
series.stroke = am4core.color('#ececec');
```

And add an [hover state](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/states/), which is applied when you hover a column:

```js
let hoverState = series.columns.template.states.create("hover");
hoverState.properties.stroke = am4core.color("red"); // change the color for each series
hoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("red"); // change the color for each series
```

Here is the complete example:

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 1),
  'itrCount': 100,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 2),
  'itrCount': 75,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 3),
  'itrCount': 80,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 4),
  'itrCount': 250,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 5),
  'itrCount': 150,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 6),
  'itrCount': 180,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 7),
  'itrCount': 95,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 8),
  'itrCount': 100,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 9),
  'itrCount': 20,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 10),
  'itrCount': 20,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 11),
  'itrCount': 20,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 12),
  'itrCount': 47,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 13),
  'itrCount': 100,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 14),
  'itrCount': 75,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 15),
  'itrCount': 80,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 16),
  'itrCount': 250,
  'pass': 35,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 17),
  'itrCount': 150,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 18),
  'itrCount': 180,
  'pass': 50,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 19),
  'itrCount': 95,
  'pass': 30,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 20),
  'itrCount': 100,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 21),
  'itrCount': 20,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 22),
  'itrCount': 20,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 23),
  'itrCount': 20,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 24),
  'itrCount': 47,
  'pass': 25,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 25),
  'itrCount': 100,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 26),
  'itrCount': 75,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 27),
  'itrCount': 80,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 28),
  'itrCount': 250,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 29),
  'itrCount': 150,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 30),
  'itrCount': 180,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}, {
  'date': new Date(2019, 4, 31),
  'itrCount': 95,
  'pass': 10,
  'error': 10
}];

const dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 0;
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0.5;
dateAxis.startLocation = 0;
dateAxis.endLocation = 1;
dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey('day', 'dd');
dateAxis.cursorTooltipEnabled = false;

const valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
valueAxis.cursorTooltipEnabled = false;

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "error";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.name = "Research";
series.stacked = true;
series.fill = am4core.color('#ececec');
series.stroke = am4core.color('#ececec');

let hoverState = series.columns.template.states.create("hover");
hoverState.properties.stroke = am4core.color("red");
hoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("red");

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series2.dataFields.valueY = "pass";
series2.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series2.name = "Marketing";
series2.stacked = true;
series2.fill = am4core.color('#ececec');
series2.stroke = am4core.color('#ececec');

let hoverState2 = series2.columns.template.states.create("hover");
hoverState2.properties.stroke = am4core.color("green");
hoverState2.properties.fill = am4core.color("green");

var series3 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series3.dataFields.valueY = "itrCount";
series3.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series3.name = "Sales";
series3.stacked = true;
series3.fill = am4core.color('#ececec');
series3.stroke = am4core.color('#ececec');

let hoverState3 = series3.columns.template.states.create("hover");
hoverState3.properties.stroke = am4core.color("blue");
hoverState3.properties.fill = am4core.color("blue");

series3.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series3.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color('#fff');
series3.tooltip.label.fill = am4core.color('#000');
series3.columns.template.tooltipY = 0;
series3.columns.template.tooltipText = 'Series: {name}\nDate: {date}\nCount: {itrCount}\nPass: {pass}\nFail: {error}';

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.lineX.disabled = true;
chart.cursor.lineY.disabled = true;
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

You can also fork and edit [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEVVzm) code pen. Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

You might want to consider some more things:

- To add a Shadow to the hover state you can create a [filter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/states/#Filters) and add a [`DropShadowFilter`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dropshadowfilter/)
- To improve your tooltip you cat take a look at [`chart.tooltipHTML`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/chart/#tooltipHTML_property) or follow [this tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/tooltips-with-rich-html-content/)
- I would not recommend using `series2.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(100);` because that can result in some overlapping SVG bugs:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Samuel your answer helped me.